# How to keep the line breaks from user input but also sanitize in blade?

Tags: laravel-4

I try to render an data from user textarea input saved in my database.

I need to keep the line breaks use nl2br,

and also want to santize to prevent malicious script by using blade {{{ }}}.

But {{{ nl2br($output) }}} wont work, the br tag would also be sanitize.

Please give me some hint, thanks.

Answer (score 26):

For **Laravel 4** users:

```
{{ nl2br(e($message)) }}
```

`e($x)` is equivalent to `{{{ $x }}}`.

**Laravel 5** users:

```
{!! nl2br(e($message)) !!}
```

`e($x)` is equivalent to `{{ $x }}`.

Comment: I had to use it like this
    {!! nl2br(e($message)) !!}

Answer (score 7):

Sawny's answer is a great one that really leverages the power of the Blade syntax well, except I would take it a step further. You can use `Blade::extend` to create your own Blade `@` shortcodes so I use the following:

```
Blade::extend(function($value, $compiler)
{
    $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('nlbr');
    return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php echo nl2br(e($2)); ?>', $value);
});
```

Now in your Blade template all have to do is something like this:

```
<div>@nlbr($sometext)</div>
```

**EDIT:** I realized someone coming across this may very well wonder, "Where do I put the `Blade::extend` function?"

To be honest, it can go in a lot of places (and it depends on if you're using Laravel 4 or 5 as to the 'best' approach).

A simple place to put it is in the `routes.php` or `global.php` files as they will get picked up with the least effort. These are however, not the *best* files to put them in and you would be best off learning to create Laravel Providers.

Answer (score -1):

simply use this remove br no need to write 
this function nl2br
it work fine

```
{!!($mylogin->title) !!}
```